# alasql attaching to sqlite

Tags: sqlite, alasql

TANACH_6_1.db  exists at the same location as the following HTML.   It runs (no errors) but nothing appears at the terminal.   Have checked and rechecked syntax and looked at several examples.   Tested sql in "SQLEXPERT".  alasql is working as I was able to create an in memory database.  Please help:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>AlaSQL - JavaScript SQL database console</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="js/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
<script src='js/alasql.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/sql.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
alasql('ATTACH SQLITE DATABASE tanach("TANACH_6_1.sqlite");
USE tanach;
SELECT verse from bookChapterVerse where bookChapterVerseID = 614',[],function(res){console.log("result:",res.pop());});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you share the part of the SQLite database, so we can check what is happen. I created the issue at github for your question: https://github.com/agershun/alasql/issues/529

Comment: The solution is to serve your HTML via a (local) webserver.